# Create an array of numbers by adding two alternating numbers

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I need to create an array of numbers by adding two alternating numbers and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I need to add 4 and then 8 alternating until I have about 200 total items in the array. The starting number should not be included. So the array should be:

[4, 12, 16, 24, 28, 36, 40, 48...]

What is the best way to accomplish that in PHP?

Comment: *"Best way"* is subjective. I'm sure there are lots of ways, one being a `for()` loop with some addition in there? I would try something and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this...

This is just one way...

```
<?php        
$sequence_array = array();
$sequence_array[0] = 4;       // Seed the initial entry
for ($i = 1; $i < 200; $i++) {
    $step = ($i % 2) ? 8 : 4; // Decide whether to add a 4 or an 8
    $sequence_array[$i] = $sequence_array[$i - 1] + $step;
}
var_dump($sequence_array);    // Lets peek at the result
```

So basically seed the 1st entry with the starting number 4.

Perform a modulo 2 on the index which is like an odd/even kind of thing, which gives us the "alternation" effect.

The $step is calculated to be either 4 or 8 based on the position being "odd/even".

You could make this more of a function and set/use variables for your alternating numbers. But I'll leave that to you if you need it :)

**Ok I couldn't let it be...**

So you can define a function like...

```
function build_alternating_array($first_value, $second_value, $total_entry_count) {
    $array = array();
    $array[0] = $first_value;   // Seed the initial value
    for ($i = 1; $i < $total_entry_count; $i++) {
        $step = ($i % 2) ? $second_value : $first_value;
        $array[$i] = $array[$i - 1] + $step;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

And call it like this...

```
$sequence_array = build_alternating_array(4, 8, 200);
var_dump($sequence_array); // Lets peek at the result
```

Answer (score 0):

just a simplified version :

```
$b = [];
$d = 0;
for($a =0; $a<=200; $a++)
{
    $d += $a % 2 ? 8 : 4;
    array_push($b , $d);
}

print_r($b);
```

Comment: That's a nicer solution than what I came up with :)